# how i get the information

Tags: php, foreach

I have this script and i need this result:

Numelem / Title / ElmPoste

```
    foreach ( $jobPrintingInfos as $jobprinting_index => $jobprinting ) {

                    $machine      = $jobprinting ['ElmPoste'];

                    //var_dump($machine);
                //    var_dump($machine);

                }

                foreach ( $GetJobResult->Components->Component as $component_index => $component ) {

                    $quote_support ='';
                    $quote_impression = '';

                        $quote_title = ($component->NumElem) . ' / ' . $component->Title . ' ' .$machine. "\r\n";

                    var_dump($quote_title);
}
```

but when i do `var_dump($quote_title)` i have the last machine not all the machine :such as

- 1/Dessus /Nesspresso
- 2/Inter/Nesspresso
- 3/Assem/Nesspresso

Thanks in advance

Comment: And from where do we get that information

Comment: `$quote_title` is being re-assigned inside the loop, you should either declare it as an array up front, then add the values onto that array (`$quote_title[] = <the string>;`), or concatenate the strings: `$quote_title .= <the string>;` (note the dot before the `=` operator)

Comment: always i have the last machine not all the machine i don't know how can i display all the machine thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i dont know the idea behind that script... but if you want that $quote_title <-- is one long String then you need to add a .

like this:

```
$quote_title .= ($component->NumElem) . ' / ' . $component->Title . ' ' .$machine. "\r\n";
```

--------------------^

or as array, then its easyer to use a for loop

Comment: always i have the last machine not all the machine i don't know how can i display all the machine thanks in advance

Comment: is $jobprinting['ElmPoste'] a 2 dimentional String array?

so $jobprinting['ElmPoste'][0] = maschine1
$jobprinting['ElmPoste'][1] = maschine2
...?

and what does the Foreach loop count, i dont know this class... may more code of that class your using...